# Composer playground unable to load sample business networks

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I am running composer playground locally and while I am connected to the Internet, it is unable to load the sample business networks when I attempt to deploy a new business network. I get following error message:

Error: could not get any sample networks.

Comment: its probable it doesn't know how to get out to the sample-networks on the NPM registry - how did you install composer playground incidentally? - also, are you using Composer v0.19.x / 1.1 of Fabric ? At first glance, it would seem it can't get out to the NPM repository to install them. The samples are also out on Github repo https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/tree/master/packages

Comment: It looks like there is some issue with the npm registry servers and its search capabilities at the moment which is causing the problem as playground makes a search request to the npm registry for available samples

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I also tried https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/ and it seems not working either.

Comment: I am facing same issue. on cloud composer playground is showing the same thing. no change!

Comment: There is still a problem with the NPM search facilities. We have released a version that uses a different repository search and is available at http://composer-playground-unstable.mybluemix.net/.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Make sure u have all your 3 Docker containers are up and running. So here is how it goes :

When u run locally, u gotta run Docker containers on your local machine.

When u want to deploy, u can do so in the Docker file or also upload to Docker hub and call the images from that path.

Good luck mate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, if you can please walk me through it, I am pretty new to this environment.

Comment: Update: I checked docker container list with "docker ps" command. I restarted all with "docker restart" command.  Now I am unable to start playground with command "container-playground". It is giving me following error: "Error: Object with ID 'undefined' in collection with ID 'chaincodes' does not exist".

Comment: Update 2: cleared cookies in browser and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to the fact that Composer Playgrounds (cp) is looking to a previous project. Besides the deletion of browser cookies for localhost:cp-listening-port (8080 by default), check that that your browser points to:

`http://localhost:cp-listening-port/login`